# ERROR: extension "postgis" is not available

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

I need to use PostGIS on Ubuntu 22.04; before starts the installation of PostGIS I checked if I already have PostgreSQL using `dpkg -l | grep postgres`. The output was empty, so I followed the official guide [here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) to install PostgreSQL.

At the end of installation process, using again `dpkg -l | grep postgres` I see:

```
ii  postgresql                                 16+256.pgdg22.04+1                      all          object-relational SQL database (supported version)
ii  postgresql-16                              16.1-1.pgdg22.04+1                      amd64        The World's Most Advanced Open Source Relational Database
ii  postgresql-client-16                       16.1-1.pgdg22.04+1                      amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 16
ii  postgresql-client-common                   256.pgdg22.04+1                         all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                          256.pgdg22.04+1                         all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
```

But after the use of `sudo apt install postgis` I see this:

```
ii  postgresql                                 16+256.pgdg22.04+1                      all          object-relational SQL database (supported version)
ii  postgresql-15                              15.5-1.pgdg22.04+1                      amd64        The World's Most Advanced Open Source Relational Database
ii  postgresql-15-postgis-3                    3.4.0+dfsg-1.pgdg22.04+1                amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 15
ii  postgresql-15-postgis-3-scripts            3.4.0+dfsg-1.pgdg22.04+1                all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 15 -- SQL scripts
ii  postgresql-16                              16.1-1.pgdg22.04+1                      amd64        The World's Most Advanced Open Source Relational Database
ii  postgresql-client-15                       15.5-1.pgdg22.04+1                      amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 15
ii  postgresql-client-16                       16.1-1.pgdg22.04+1                      amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 16
ii  postgresql-client-common                   256.pgdg22.04+1                         all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                          256.pgdg22.04+1                         all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
ii  postgresql-postgis                         3.4.0+dfsg-1.pgdg22.04+1                amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- Metapackage
ii  postgresql-postgis-scripts                 3.4.0+dfsg-1.pgdg22.04+1                all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- SQL scripts metapackage
```

I don't undestand why PostgreSQL 15 is installed. When I try to add postgis's extension(`sudo -u postgres psql -c "create extension postgis;"`) to a DB I see this message:

```
ERROR:  extension "postgis" is not available
DETAIL:  Could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/16/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory.
HINT:  The extension must first be installed on the system where PostgreSQL is running.
```

Comment: You installed the wrong PostGIS.

Comment: Ok @LaurenzAlbe , but what is the rigth way?

Comment: What do you get for `apt search postgis`?

Comment: Hi. You installed postgis for postgres 15, but postgres 16 server is running..

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, using `apt search postgis` I found and installed the right postgis for postgres 16, thank you